# R how to find the intersection of a subest of vectors in a list

Tags: r, list, vector, intersection

I have a list of vectors (characters). For example:

```
my_list <- list(c("a", "b", "c"), 
                c("a", "b", "c", "d"), 
                c("e", "d"))
```

For the intersection of all these three vectors, I could use: `Reduce(intersect, my_list)`. But as you can see, there is no common element in all three vectors.

Then, what if I want to find the common element that appears "at least" a certain amount of times in the list? Such as: `somefunction(my_list, time=2)` would give me `c("a", "b", "c", "d")` because those elements appear two times.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can convert this to a `data.table` and do the group by action to get the elements

```
library(data.table)
setDT(stack(setNames(my_list, seq_along(my_list))))[,
           if(uniqueN(ind)==2) values , values]$values
#[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

---

A `base R` option would be to `unlist` the 'my_list', find the frequency count with the replicated sequence of 'my_list' using `table`, get the column sums, check whether it is equal to 2 and use that index to subset the `names`.

```
tblCount <- colSums(table(rep(seq_along(my_list), lengths(my_list)), unlist(my_list)))
names(tblCount)[tblCount==2]
#[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you assume that each element will appear no more than once in a vector, you can "unlist" your vectors and count the frequency.

Here, using `dplyr` functions

```
library(dplyr)
my_list %>% unlist %>% data_frame(v=.) %>% count(v) %>% filter(n>=2) %>% .[["v"]]
```

Or base functions

```
subset(as.data.frame(table(unlist(my_list))), Freq>=2)$Var1
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
my_list %>%
  purrr::map(~ .) %>%
  purrr::reduce(.f = dplyr::intersect, .x = .)
```